# Powershell : Extracting data from log file to create a new object

Tags: powershell

I am stumbling along with powershell.

I have script that parses the same log file on hundreds of PC's extracting two types of transactions we are interested in.

this line does the pattern match saving each line of log in one variable that contains multiple lines.  I convert the match object to string so I can split it later on.

```
$strLogEvents = select-string -path \\$Cmpname\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\outlook.* -pattern '(doFolderDocSearch ends, duration)|(doDocSearch ends, duration)' | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString()}
```

here is what $StrLogEvents holds for a single PC

```
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log:325:Wed 08/17 10:24:44.983 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [10728] System call doDocSearch ends, duration 60203 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:886:Fri 08/05 16:23:14.249 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call DoFolderDocSearch ends, duration 1796 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:963:Fri 08/05 16:23:27.901 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call DoFolderDocSearch ends, duration 250 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:1046:Fri 08/05 16:23:41.625 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call doDocSearch ends, duration 171 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:1422:Sun 08/07 23:08:49.107 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call DoFolderDocSearch ends, duration 250 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:1786:Sun 08/07 23:09:42.750 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call doDocSearch ends, duration 407 ms
\\naimc\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\OUTLOOK.log_bak:1847:Sun 08/07 23:10:05.494 PerformanceContext:  59:Info2 [12204] System call doDocSearch ends, duration 454 ms
```

For each line I am only interesting in retraining the computername, Date, time, Type of system call , Duration in milliseconds.

I can further break-up the string array with this :

```
$ParsedLogEvents = $strLogEvents | ForEach-Object {$_.split("\, ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)}
```

The string in $ParsedLogEvents now contains one clean line for each "piece" of data

Example : Each item is on it's own line. I have added *** to denote the lines I want to keep.

```
naimc***-PCName
c$
ProgramData
IS
Logs
DMS
OUTLOOK.log_bak:4602:Mon
08/15*** -Date
14:36:01.667 -Time
PerformanceContext:
59:Info2
[10928]
System
call
doDocSearch ***-EventType
ends
duration
47 ***-Duration
ms
naimc
c$
ProgramData
Osler
IS
Logs
DMS
OUTLOOK.log_bak:4610:Mon
08/15 
14:36:01.748 
PerformanceContext:
59:Info2
[10928]
System
call
doDocSearch 
ends
duration
31 
ms
```

I think I have to process each line as single variable. (can't figure out how do this simple part). After I could simply use the $ParsedLogEvents[lineNumber] to return the records for the rows I want to retain to create a hash table or an object. this would allow me to save as CSV or export to SQL datbase. I can't do this now because each line all of original events are together inside of this one big array.

Any suggestions ? Am I heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Do the field-parsing in `Select-String` via named groups of regular expression pattern:

```
$report = select-string `
    -path \\$Cmpname\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\outlook.* `
    -pattern ('(?<date>.+? .+?) ' +
        '(?<time>.+?) .+? ' +
        '(?<syscall>doFolderDocSearch|doDocSearch) ends, duration ' +
        '(?<duration>.+?) ms') `
| %{
    $g = $_.matches[0].groups
    @{
        computer = $Cmpname
        date = $g['date'].value
        time = $g['time'].value
        syscall = $g['syscall'].value
        duration = $g['duration'].value
    }
}
```

Will produce an array of objects accessible as `$report[1].computer`, `$report[1].date`, and so on:

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> date                           Wed 08/17
> time                           10:24:44.983
> syscall                        doDocSearch
> computer                       naimc
> duration                       60203
> ```

Comment: Very nice but too hardcore for my understanding. For some reason your raw suggestion did not return any results but I did an addaption

Comment: Maybe you're using powershell2 or 3? The code runs as is on PS4.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice ! This is 1st example I see of named groups of regular expressions

For some reason your raw sample did not return any results it ran for a few minutes but nothing was captured.  I had to break your example in small parts to understand the concept

I kept my basic line which does the initial parsing, left it in the matchinfo format.

```
$strLogEvents = select-string -path \\$Cmpname\c$\ProgramData\IS\Logs\DMS\outlook.* -pattern '(doFolderDocSearch ends, duration)|(doDocSearch ends, duration)'
```

them passed the Matchinfo.Line in a second select string, which has your code textual works and is fast.

```
$report = $strLogEvents | select-string -Inputobject {$_.line} -pattern ('(?<date>.+? .+?) ' + '(?<time>.+?) .+? ' + '(?<syscall>doFolderDocSearch|doDocSearch) ends, duration ' + '(?<duration>.+?) ms') | %{
    $g = $_.matches[0].groups
    @{
        computer = $Cmpname
        date = $g['date'].value
        time = $g['time'].value
        syscall = $g['syscall'].value
        duration = $g['duration'].value
    }
}
```